# PostgreSQL Exclusion constraint with comparison predicate

Tags: postgresql

There is simple to mimic unique constraint like

```
create table foo(x int, exclude (x with =));
```

But how is it possible to use `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` instead of `=` (so there is only one `NULL` value in the table)?

Creating function like `f(anyelement, anyelement)` and operator fails because `null` have unknown type. So yet another question: is it possible to wrap `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` predicate into operator in PostgreSQL?

Be patient, I not searching an alternative solution, I know its a lot :)

Furthermore reading: [Comparison operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html)

Comment: There might be a neater way, but can you specify the right type for the null? `NULL::int`

Comment: @Ryan Surely. But I asking for general solution.

Comment: Related (no dupe, but may be useful): https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60342/can-is-distinct-from-be-combined-with-any-or-all-somehow/60357. This question might fit dba.SE, too.

Comment: (@ErwinBrandstetter, last time I searching for Postgres wik about distinct on (...) Could you post this link?)

Comment: You mean this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564

Comment: A not very comfortable solution would be to define your own operator with `CREATE OPERATOR`.

Comment: @clemens Yes it is alternative to create operators `int - int`, `text - text`, `json-json` `range-range` etc.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter (No. Not your answer (but it was in some of it by link-link-link-...), but PostgreSQL wiki. There was brief simple explanation why `group by` and `distinct on` are slow and how to do it faster with recursive CTE)

Comment: What's the problem with your function exactly? There shouldn't be any "unknown types" involved when evaluating an exclusion constraint...

Comment: @NickBarnes `my_function(1, null)` and `my_function(null, 1)` works fine. but `my_function(null, null)` caused an error `could not determine polymorphic type because input has type "unknown"`.

Comment: @Abelisto: Why does that matter? The inputs won't have type `unknown` when you use it as a table constraint...

Comment: @NickBarnes True. But if i wrote some code I'd like to have it reusable as most as possible. Thanks for your time in anywhere.

Comment: @Abelisto: Oh, then you may be thinking of this one, discussing rCTE solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860; with a link to this wiki page: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan (latest updates there are from me as well). The keyword is "loose index scan".

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yes! It was nightmare that I remember it but can not find :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to create a function and an operator that corresponds to `NOT DISTINCT TO`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ndist(anyelement, anyelement) RETURNS boolean
   IMMUTABLE CALLED ON NULL INPUT LANGUAGE sql
   AS 'SELECT $1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM $2';

CREATE OPERATOR === (
   PROCEDURE = ndist,
   LEFTARG = anyelement,
   RIGHTARG = anyelement,
   COMMUTATOR = "==="
);
```

This will fail if both arguments are untyped NULLs:

```
test=> SELECT NULL === NULL;
ERROR:  could not determine polymorphic type because input has type unknown
```

One solution is to use overloading and define the same function and operator for every type you need:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ndist(integer, integer) RETURNS boolean
   IMMUTABLE CALLED ON NULL INPUT LANGUAGE sql
   AS 'SELECT $1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM $2';

CREATE FUNCTION ndist(text, text) RETURNS boolean
   IMMUTABLE CALLED ON NULL INPUT LANGUAGE sql
   AS 'SELECT $1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM $2';

CREATE OPERATOR === (
   PROCEDURE = ndist,
   LEFTARG = integer,
   RIGHTARG = integer,
   COMMUTATOR = "==="
);

CREATE OPERATOR === (
   PROCEDURE = ndist,
   LEFTARG = text,
   RIGHTARG = text,
   COMMUTATOR = "==="
);
```

Then the example will work:

```
test=> SELECT NULL === NULL;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

This is because the type resolution rules will prefer the operator on `text` in that case.

But all this will not allow you to create an exclusion constraint, because your operator is not associated with an operator class, which is necessary to determine what kind of index is to be used.

You would have to create a matching function for each of the `btree` [*index method strategies*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xindex.html#XINDEX-STRATEGIES) and define an operator class for `btree` with these functions.

Comment: I always forget that anything in PostgreSQL could be implicitly converted to/from text.

Comment: @Abelisto: About implicit casts: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194975/how-to-avoid-implicit-type-casts-in-postgresql/194983#194983